# JQuery get option text based on same li element

Tags: html, jquery

I am working on a select option where I do not know how can I get the text from the option base on the option value.

For example I would like to get the text "Danish" if the value is da,

The html of the option select is as below

```
<div id="language" class="dd-container" style="width: 333px;">
  <div class="dd-select">
     <input class="dd-selected-value" name="language" type="hidden" value="en">
     <a class="dd-selected"><label class="dd-selected-text">English</label></a>
     <span class="dd-pointer"></span>
  </div>

    <ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close">
        <li><a class="dd-option dd-option-selected"> 
            <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="en"> 
            <label class="dd-option-text">English</label></a>
        </li>

        <li><a class="dd-option"> 
            <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="da"> 
            <label class="dd-option-text">Danish</label></a>
        </li>

        <li><a class="dd-option"> 
            <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="nl"> 
            <label class="dd-option-text">Dutch</label></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my jquery, i am able to get the value with the below statment

```
 var langname = $('li a.dd-option input.dd-option-value[value="da"]').val();
 alert(langname);
```

But I am not able to get the text with this

```
 var langname = $('li a.dd-option input.dd-option-value[value="da"]').text();
 alert(langname);
```

Does anyone has a solution to this?

Comment: You can also use siblings method to get the text as `$('li a.dd-option input.dd-option-value[value="da"]').siblings('label').text();` , you can use text() or html() to get the text with in the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

label is sibling of input element. You need to use correct selector to target the next label element:

```
 $('li a.dd-option input.dd-option-value[value="da"]').next().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [**closest**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to achieve this like below:

```
 var langname = $('li a.dd-option input.dd-option-value[value="da"]').closest('a').text();

 alert(langname);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f144gkc/) for same